# how to embed audio in flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

i want to play a sound when user click on the button in flex 3. My flex application will generate the images one by one. For each image, one sound should come in background. Any ideas? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to write something like this:

```
[Embed(source="myfile.mp3")]
[Bindable] //Not required. Just an example of using multiple meta tags.  
public var soundCls:Class;
```

This will give you the ability to reference the file via the class name

Comment: can i have multiple sound files/classes and play them one after the other?

Comment: I guess so. you can embed more with this method. Playing them is out of the scope and you would need to listen for the end of the playing track then start playing the new one.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation created by Adobe is quite ok.. you can find the link [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Sound_01.html). You will also find code samples.