# Can't play sound file in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I wrote a game in flex and that game has sound. I load the sound from an asset like this to play the sound file, this is the function:

```
public function playSound(value:String, vol:Number):void
{

 mySound=new Sound();
 var urlRequest:URLRequest=new URLRequest(value);
 mySound.load(urlRequest);
 sChannel=mySound.play(0, 0, new SoundTransform(vol, 0));
}
```

When I'd like to play the sound I call it like this:

```
playSound("sounds/abc.mp3", 1)
```

The "sounds" in the package in the current project. It works fine when I build in eclipse, but when I put that game on the web, I can't hear the music.

Could anyone tell me how to fix please

Comment: Do you mean when you put it on the web you *can't* hear the music?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever tried to modified your sound file by

1. Remove all metadata in the sound file.
2. Export it to a new MP3 file.
3. Is it too large to load? Try to add error event to listen.

Answer (score 0):

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest=new URLRequest(value);
```

You're passing this a relative path, so when it's running on a remote machine it's looking there for the sound and obviously not finding it. You need to embed the sound, as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4276485/900873):

```
[Embed(source="myfile.mp3")]
[Bindable] //Not required. Just an example of using multiple meta tags.  
public var soundCls:Class;
```

Then, I'm a bit rusty, but I believe it's

```
sChannel = new soundCls().play(0, 0, new SoundTransform(vol, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this.

```
    var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("assets/sound/sound3.mp3");
    var sound:Sound= new Sound(urlReq);

    sound.play();
```